# Results in linear algebra that depend on the choice of field

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields, gm.general-mathematics

Linear algebra as we learn it as undergraduates usually holds for any field (even though we usually learn it for the complex, or real, numbers).

I am looking for a list of concepts, and results, in linear algebra that actually depend on the choice of field.

To start I propose the notion of an complex valued inner product. Here the anti-linear axiom requires an involution on the field.

Comment: The famous $\operatorname{Ker} A = \operatorname{Ker}\left(A^T A\right)$ (which is used, e.g., in the construction of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse) requires the field to be ordered.

Comment: The theory of skew-symmetric matrices depends on the field unless one is careful and studies alternating matrices instead (as one should 95% of the time).

Comment: Solvability of $AB-BA=I$ for $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ depends on the field characteristic. Also diagonalizability of the $n\times n$ all 1's matrix.

Comment: diagonalizability of rotation matrix

Comment: I find the example (complex-valued inner product) not really convincing. Algebraically, a Hermitian form is rather a real object (defined from a quadratic Galois extension, etc). Or, alternatively, one views it defined from a field *endowed* with an involution (not from a field on which there "exists" an involution). (By the way when one complexifies the real object $(\mathbf{C},$conjugation), one obtains a complex object which is isomorphic to $(\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{C},$flip).

Comment: It seems that a [recent nCat post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2021/09/axioms_for_the_category_of_hil_1.html), referring back to an [old nCat post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/12/solers_theorem.html), may be interesting in this connection even if it does not really answer the question as asked. \\ @darijgrinberg, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404724/results-in-linear-algebra-that-depend-on-the-choice-of-field#comment1037049_404724), what is an alternating matrix?

Comment: @LSpice: A skew-symmetric matrix with zeroes on its main diagonal.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, ah, OK, alternating matrix = matrix of alternating form.  Thanks!

Comment: The premise of this question is incorrect because the part of such a course involving inner products does not work over general fields (positive-definiteness as opposed to mere nondegeneracy of a symmetric bilinear form, square roots of inner products, and the spectral theorem).

Comment: Sure whether the field is finite/infinite, algebrically closed/not closed, characteristic 2/not 2, makes a difference in many situations

Comment: *"even though we usually learn it for the complex, or real, numbers"* Hmm, this seems to be quite a sweeping generalization . If memory serves well, every linear algebra course that I have been involved with so far, was taught over general fields.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, I think [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404724/results-in-linear-algebra-that-depend-on-the-choice-of-field#comment1037162_404724) matters quite a bit where and for whom you teach.  I teach at a small US university where the linear-algebra course serves many non-math majors, and most of the course is taught over just the real numbers, with even the complex numbers mentioned only when necessary.

Comment: @LSpice: Even big fancy places usually teach most of their linear algebra over R or C (eg I taught a section of such a class at MIT as a postdoc, and there were many sections).

Comment: This might not be quite what you're looking for, but any property of a [binary matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_matroid) or of a matroid representable over some field that is not a [regular matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_matroid) is potentially an answer to your question. For example, let's say I want to find 7 vectors with the linear independence structure of a [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane). I can do this over a field of characteristic 2 but not over other fields.

Comment: @LSpice: Yes indeed, it clearly depends on a lot of variables (among them: location, intended audience, preferences of the instructor, etc.). That's why I described the OP's sentence as a "sweeping generalization": it is true in a significant number of situations, but far from universally true.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341854/if-the-field-of-a-vector-space-werent-characteristic-zero-then-what-would-chan

Comment: I feel like the right setting for linear algebra is over $*$-fields and not just fields. A $*$-field is a field equipped with an involution. The leading example is the field of complex numbers equipped with complex conjugation as the involution

Comment: This then includes things like the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, Singular Value Decomposition and so on into the broader linear algebra. Otherwise they're limited to just $\mathbb C$, which I find a bit awkward

Comment: @darijgrinberg You said that $\ker(A)=\ker(A^\intercal A)$ *requires* the field being ordered. Do you mean that, if this is true for every $A$, then there exists an ordering of the base field?

Comment: @Z.M: Yes, this is true. Assume that $\ker A = \ker\left(A^T A\right)$ holds for every $k\times 1$-matrix $A = \left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k\right)^T \in F^{k\times 1}$. This means that a sum of the form $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_k^2$ (where $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k \in F$) cannot be $0$ unless all of $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ are zero. But this means that the field $F$ is [formally real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field). And by a known fact, this implies that it can be totally ordered such that the result is a totally ordered field.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The existence of Chevalley–Jordan decompositions depends on the perfectness of the field.

Answer (score 32):

A finite-dimensional vector space is a union of finitely many proper subspaces if and only if the underlying field is finite.

Comment: Or how about just "a finite dimensional vector space is finite"?

Comment: @Steven, it's true that one direction of the "if and only if" is trivial (although, come to think of it, I should insist on the dimension being at least two), but the other direction requires an argument.

Comment: I would prefer to replace vector spaces by affine spaces in this proposition. The version for affine spaces follows more directly from induction (passing to hyperplanes).

Comment: A finite dimensional vector space is the union of countably many proper subspaces if and only if the underlying field is countable.

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404724/results-in-linear-algebra-that-depend-on-the-choice-of-field#comment1037049_404724): when the characteristic of your field is not $2$, "skew-symmetric" and "alternating" are equivalent conditions on a bilinear form. In characteristic $2$, alternating implies skew-symmetric (which is also equivalent to symmetric), but not vice versa.

For example, multiplication as a bilinear form on $\mathbb{F}_2$ is (skew-)symmetric, but not alternating since $1 \cdot 1 = 1 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 23):

Existence of Jordan canonical form (requires algebraically closed field).

Comment: Not really. The theorem should be stated in the form "if the characteristic polynomial splits over the base field, the operator admits a Jordan form", the requirement of the field being closed is there only to force the assumption.

Comment: @Andrei Smolensky: yes, sure. But maybe Brauer Suzuki by that phrase was meaning "existence of Jordan canonical form [for all operators]"

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky, well, add the clause "for all endomorphisms of all finite dimensional vector spaces" if that feels more satisfying ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ You can almost always replace the hypotehsis that a field is algebraically closed by one demanding that certain specific polynomials split. One generally does not.

Comment: Existence of eigevalues "for all endomorphisms of all finite dimensional vector spaces" requires algebraically closed fields.

Comment: But there are natural generalizations which work over any field, such as the "primary rational canonical form". These are given in terms of companion matrices of irreducible polynomials. Of course in the algebraically closed case this just gives $1 \times 1$ matrices $(\lambda)$, corresponding to polynomial $x - \lambda$.

Comment: This is the same as @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404737).

Answer (score 20):

For a finite field ${\mathbb F}_q$, you may calculate the probability that the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is $0$. This probability has a limit $\pi_q$ as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. Amazingly, this $\pi_q$ does depend upon $q$. In particular, it is $>\frac1q$.

To be more precise, the probability that $\det M\ne0$ is, for fixed $n$,
$$\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{q^m}\right).$$
Its limit as $n\rightarrow+\infty$ is non trivial and is strictly less than the first factor $1-\frac1q$. Hence
$$\pi_q=1-\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{q^m}\right)>\frac1q.$$
Notice that this can be expressed in terms of Dedekind's eta function.

Comment: Implicitly you're using the uniform distribution on the set of such matrices here, right? I wonder if there is some other "natural" distribution where the answer does not depend on $q$. (I also don't totally see why the dependence on $q$, for the uniform distribution, should be "amazing.")

Comment: Could we list some example values of $\pi_q$? The bounds $1/q < \pi_q \leq 5/8$ do not immediately preclude the possibility that $\pi_q$ is independent of $q$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk The  log of the product in question gives an absolutely convergent series in $q$ which is increasing in $q$.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure it's very suprising. It's certainly not for $n=1$ :-)

Comment: Why is it "amazing" that this limiting proportion depends on $q$?

Comment: @KConrad What is amazing is that the proportion is never $\frac1q$, even in the limit.

Answer (score 12):

The trueness of the statement "two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if their dual spaces are isomorphic" depends on the cardinality of the field (and the underlying set-theoretic axioms).

Comment: What is this dependence?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk - Let me give two examples. But first note, if we accept the axiom of choice, then, for an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $k$ we have $\dim(V^\ast)=|k|^{\dim(V)}$. 

**Example 1:** Let $|k|=|2^\mathbb{R}|$ and $\dim(V)=|\mathbb{N}|, \dim(W)=|\mathbb{R}|$. Hence $V^\ast,W^\ast$ are isomorphic because they have the same dimension $|k|$. So, for $k$ the statement doesn't hold.

Comment: **Example 2:** Let $k$ be a countable field and $V,W$ be infinite dimensional vector spaces over $k$ such that $V^\ast\cong W^\ast$. Hence $|2^{\dim(V)}|=\dim(V^\ast)=\dim(W^\ast)=|2^{\dim(W)}|$ and by the generalized continuum hypothesis $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$ follows. So, for $k$ the statement is true.

Answer (score 12):

The vector space of multilinear maps $\prod_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is infinite dimensional, unless the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$, in which case it is one dimensional.

Comment: This exercise is a bit difficult. Do you mind including a hint?

Comment: @AndréHenriques The vector space $$colim_n (V_1 \otimes \dots \otimes V_n) \otimes \Bbb F\{\prod_{k>n} V_k\}$$ has the right universal property to accept a universal multilinear map from $\prod V_k$, and the colimit description makes it easier to check when two elements are equal (roughly, only when there is a simple reason so)

Comment: yes and then one can replace $\prod_{k>n}V_k$ by $\prod_{n>k}(V_k\setminus 0)$ to see that it is one-dimensional for $V_k=\mathbb{F}_2$. one can also write down a basis for the tensor product given by a choice of representatitives of $(\prod_n (V_k\setminus 0))/\sim$ where two sequences are equivalent, iff they differ only in finitely many places.

Comment: @HenrikRüping : Notice this typographical difference: $$(\prod_n (V_k\setminus 0))/\sim$$
$$(\prod_n (V_k\setminus 0))/{\sim}$$ The $\text{“}{\sim}\text{”}$ symbol has horizontal space between it and whatever is to its left or right because it's a binary relation symbol, except when nothing is to its left or right. Since that spacing is not appropriate in the expression above, you can code it as `(\prod_n (V_k\setminus 0))/{\sim}` with {curly braces} enclosing it. That's the way to do it.

Answer (score 11):

Let $U_n$ be a $n \times n$ Jordan block with $1$'s on the diagonal (unipotent Jordan block).

Then for $n,m > 0$ the Kronecker product $U_n \otimes U_m$ has a Jordan normal form over any field, but the Jordan blocks that occur depend on the characteristic of the field.

There is a closed formula in characteristic $p = 0$ and $p \geq m+n$, in which case $U_n \otimes U_m$ is similar to the matrix $$U_{n+m-1} \oplus U_{n+m-3} \oplus \cdots \oplus U_{n+m-2s+1}$$ where $s = \min(m,n)$.

But in general there is no such formula (except recursive ones). For example in characteristic $p > 0$ you get $$U_p \otimes U_p \sim U_p \oplus \cdots \oplus U_p\  (p \text{ times})$$

Answer (score 10):

A symmetric tensor is a linear combination of tensor powers over a field of characteristic 0 (or large enough), but not always.

(The underlying reason is that polarization formulae contain denominators.)

Answer (score 10):

One such property I had in an exam once was this one:

Are $A, B, C$ linear independent vectors?

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}, \ B = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \ C = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We defined one way to tests that property over the determinant:

$ \text{det}(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix})$

which is $2$. So are they linearly independent? Only in a field where $2 \neq 0$. In a field where $0 = 1 + 1 = 2$, we can confirm that $A = B + C$.

Answer (score 9):

Copied into an answer from a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404724/results-in-linear-algebra-that-depend-on-the-choice-of-field#comment1037048_404724) of D. Grinberg:

> The famous $\ker A=\ker(A^T A)$
> (which is used, e.g., in the construction of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse) requires the field to be ordered.

Comment: I think that the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is based on $\ker(A)=\ker(A^*A)$ which is true over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 8):

In representation theory (a bit beyond *pure* linear algebra):

*Maschke's theorem*: a finite-dimensional representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $k$ with characteristic not dividing the order of $G$ is semisimple.

*Weyl's theorem on complete reducibility*: every finite-dimensional representation of a semisimple Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero is semisimple.

So in characteristic zero it is always semisimple, but in positive characteristic, not always.

Answer (score 7):

The existence of two commuting nilpotent matrices of specified Jordan types depends on the characteristic *and* size of the field. This was first shown in my [joint paper](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/GLClasses20.pdf) with John Britnell, *Types and classes of commuting matrices*, J. Lond. Math. Soc. **83** (2011) 470–492.

Specifically, Proposition 4.7 states that there are matrices
of Jordan types $(n,n)$ and $(n+1,n-1)$ that commute over $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ if and only if $n$ is not divisible by $p(p^{2r}-1)/e$, where

$$e = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $p=2$} \\ 2 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

The smallest example of this type is that there are matrices of Jordan types $(6,6)$ and $(7,5)$ that commute with entries in $\mathbb{F}_{4}$, $\mathbb{F}_8$, and so on, but no such matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Section 4.4 of the paper gives some further field-dependent results of this type, including a classification of all commuting Jordan types labelled by partitions with at most two parts.

Answer (score 5):

The subgroup of $\text{GL}_n(k)$ generated by diagonalizable matrices is the whole of $\text{GL}_n(k)$, unless $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ in which case it is trivial.

Comment: There are a number of results on matrix groups over fields that have counterexamples for small finite fields and small matrix sizes. For example, if $n \geq 2$ and $F$ is a field then (i) ${\rm GL}_n(F)' = {\rm SL}_n(F)$ unless $n = 2$ and $|F| = 2$, (ii) ${\rm SL}_n(F)' = {\rm SL}_n(F)$ unless $n = 2$ and $|F| \leq 3$ and (iii) the group ${\rm PSL}_n(F) := {\rm SL}_n(F)/Z$ is simple unless $n =  2$ and $|F| \leq 3$.

Comment: Yes of course you're right. That particular result just hit my brain when I read HenrikRüping's above post about multilinear forms, because of the fact that the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ has such a singular behaviour (in my example : full group / trivial group).

Answer (score 4):

This is a very simple fact that besides linear algebra, uses just a bit of geometry/topology.
Over the reals, there are pairs of conjugate rotations, say $A$ and $B$, such that $A$ cannot be continuously conjugated into $B$, within $\mathbb R$, but it can do so over $\mathbb C$.
For example, take
$$
A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   c & -s \\
   s & c \\
  \end{array} } \right] 
$$
with $c=\cos(\theta)$ and $s=\sin(\theta)$, for some generic real $\theta$, and let $B$ be the transpose of $A$.
Then $B$ and $A$ are conjugate via a matrix of negative determinant, so $A$ cannot be continuously conjugated to  $B$ unless we work over the complexes.

Comment: Does "$A$ can be continuously conjugated into $B$" mean "there is a continuous path in the conjugacy class of $A$ from $A$ to $B$"?

Comment: Yes. First, you notice that the conjugacy class of $A$ and $B$ are the same (they are conjugate). Then you find that one can only be conjugated to the other via a matrix of negative determinant. Then, any possible conjugating path, in the real coefficients situation, would have to cross zero determinant.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning explicitly that, in addition, $A$ can be conjugated (in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$) to itself only by a matrix of positive determinant (which can be verified directly, or, I suppose, deduced from the fact that $A$ and $B$ are conjugate, but only by matrices of negative determinant).

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious, but easy to forget, that in a field of finite characteristic a non-zero vector can be perpendicular to itself. This has consequences which can be counterintuitive.

For example, a basis for $S$ combined with a basis for $S^\perp$ need not be a basis for the whole space.

Comment: Is this not also true for the vector $(1, \sqrt{-1}) \in \mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: @ Martin Seysen  Yes, depending on how you define "perpindicular". In the complex case it's common to conjugate the second vector of the inner product, in which case it's not. My point was that in finite fields the concept of orthogonality is extensively used (to define dual codes, for example) but that the properties of such differ substantially from the real case.

Answer (score 0):

The following is true if the field is infinite and false for finite fields.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with subspace $W$. If $f:V\to V$ is linear and $V$ is the smallest $f$-invariant subspace containing $W$, then there exists a $v\in W$ such that the minimal polynomial of $f$ equals the minimal polynomial of $f$ for the vector $v$.

One nice proof of the true "infinite" version uses the answer of Gerry Myerson.

Comment: Does this depend on $g$ itself, rather than just depending on im $g$? If not I feel like it would be more clearly phrased by dropping reference to $g$ and just referring to $U =$ im $g$ as any subspace of $V$ not contained in a proper $f$-invariant subspace.

Comment: @Bma: Good point, thank you. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space is $1$, but $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is infinite-dimensional.